# Fix mathmode font while using Arial

Tags: fontspec

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Arial}
\begin{document}
$\sin C$
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I ensure that the default math font is used in mathmode? For text it is fine, say `\text{sample}`. If you notice in the above diagram, the font changes to Arial.

Comment: `no-math` option to `fontspec`?

Comment: @Stephen That worked! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[mathrm=sym]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Arial}
\begin{document}
    $\sin C$
\end{document}
```

[image]